# Can Angular.js do Interpolation in Jade templates in a Script Tag?

Tags: node.js, express, angularjs, pug

I'm using angular with jade templates and I have some javascript in the template:

```
script(type='text/javascript')
    console.log('{{name}}');
```

In my angular controller I do something like the following:

```
$scope.name = "Bhoutrous";
```

I can get {{name}} to interpolate correctly anywhere else in the template just as long as it is not under a script tag. For me, angular throws a "SyntaxError: invalid property id" error. I'm wondering if it's a Jade issue or is there a work-around.  I need to have the contents of the'name' variable passed to a js function when the page loads.

**UPDATE**

I know that it can work with regular templates. fiddle of the example below: http://jsfiddle.net/atentaten/mnscA/

Does anyone have any experience in doing something like this using jade?

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="UserCtrl">
    <p>{{data}}</p>
    <div id="dat"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
       function doit(text){
          var el = document.getElementById("dat");
           el.innerHTML = text;
       }

      doit( '{{data}}' );  
    </script>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var app=angular.module('myApp', []);

function UserCtrl($scope) {
        $scope.data = "Green Applese";

};
```

Comment: Have you looked at the outputted HTML to see what's actually being rendered and consumed by AngularJS?

Answer (score 0):

Angular does interpolation in DOM elements. Contents of script tags and other random strings aren't interpolated. You can access Angular services, including the `$interpolate` service, outside of the Angular application lifecycle; [I answered a question much like this yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14796047/is-it-possible-in-angularjs-to-use-data-bindings-inside-a-classic-javascript-fun/14796477#14796477). But, like in that answer, I suggest that this is not really a good way to write applications with Angular.

Comment: Well, strings are being interpolated in script tags per the fiddle. However, I solved the problem by adding a function to the $scope: $scope.myfunction = function(){ //the needed variable is obtained from the $routeParams, do stuff with it.} In the template I invoked the function like this {{myfunction()}} and it worked perfectly.  Is this considered a good way? If not, what would be the best approach? I don't want two way data binding, just need to pass a parameter to a function that get's called when the page loads.

Comment: Also, in the example for the other question, which file/location does the js reside?

Comment: I'm not really sure from the question what you're trying to accomplish. If you want to run a function on a controller's scope when something first loads, I would probably use the `ngInit` directive: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngInit In the other question, the JavaScript can be in any file that the page loads.

Comment: We've been using both Hogan.js and Angular templating where I work for nearly a year (mostly for SEO-related reasons). If there are server-side templating vars we want to pass to Angular, we typically do it in an ng-init (as mentioned above). It's not a perfect solution (e.g. it works well for strings, but gets complicated with objects), but it works. And for anyone who says "Using server-side templating is not the angular way" . . . SEO has obviously never mattered to you. Until bots start running javascript, you're stuck with _some_ kind of hack, and this seemed like the simplest hack to us.

Answer (score 0):

A form which work for my in **jade**

```
div(ng-controller="UserCtrl",anotherAttr="yourValue")
    p#dataBind {{data}}
    div#dat
    script.
       function doit(text){
          $("#dat").html(text)
       }      
       doit($("#dataBind").text());
```

Note the dot "." after the script tag, this allow put js code in **jade**