# AngularJS string within an inline script tag

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to use an ng-repeat loop to place a string within an inline script tag and it's not working. This is the markup:

```
<div ng-repeat="advert in adverts" class="col-lg-5 col-sm-12" >
  <div style="height:250px;" >
    <div id='{{ advert.slot }}' class="" style='height:250px; width:300px;'>
      <script type='text/javascript'>
        googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('{{ advert.slot }}'); });
      </script>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And this is what `{{ advert.slot }}` is referencing in my controller:

```
$scope.adverts = [
  {slot: 'div-gpt-ad-1456171715291-0'},
  {slot: 'div-gpt-ad-1456171148740-0'},
  {slot: 'div-gpt-ad-1456171224228-0'},
  {slot: 'div-gpt-ad-1456171473386-0'},
  {slot: 'div-gpt-ad-1456171316677-0'},
  {slot: 'div-gpt-ad-1456171401296-0'}
];
```

It works for the first reference within the id slot, but when I inspect element on the script it's not populating it within the inline string.

Comment: This should help.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14796047/is-it-possible-in-angularjs-to-use-data-bindings-inside-a-classic-javascript-fun

Answer (score 0):

you should be using [ng-init](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) for this

```
<div ng-repeat="advert in adverts" class="col-lg-5 col-sm-12" >
  <div style="height:250px;" >
    <div id='{{ advert.slot }}' class="" style='height:250px; width:300px;' ng-init="someFunction(advert)">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In your controller :

```
$scope.someFunction = function(advert){
    googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display( advert.slot); });
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be displaying the script tags at all.

Comment: I moved the javascript code to the controller and the code is called from ng-init. so no script tag is required